# How to split string into dictionary and return a specific dictionary value?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

Very new to Python here.

I have a python script that evaluates each line of a data contract and pulls out certain values based on a set of criteria. I need to modify the script to now also extract the Name value from a DataMember line. However, I'm having trouble getting my new ExtractDataMemberName function to work.

First, I have a function that iterates through each line of a file using this `for` statement:

```
for line in file:
        if IsDataMemberAttribute(line):
            name = ExtractDataMemberName(line)
        elif ...
```

In the `ExtractDataMemberName(line)` function, I need to return the `Name` value from strings like the sample input line shown below. Note that the number and order of attributes within the DataMember line can vary.

**Sample input:**

```
"[DataMember(Name = "version", EmitDefaultValue = false, Order = 5)]"
```

**Expected output:**

```
version
```

I've tried several approaches, including trying to lstrip `[DataMember("` and rstrip `)]`, then trying to split the resulting string into a dictionary so that I can find the Name value, but I can't get it to work.

Can anyone recommend the best way to extract the Name value from a string like that?

Comment: use regular expressions. e.g. http://txt2re.com/index-python.php3?s=[DataMember(Name%20=%20%22version%22,%20EmitDefaultValue%20=%20false,%20Order%20=%205)]&7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using split is a bit ugly:

```
s = '[DataMember(Name = "version", EmitDefaultValue = false, Order = 5)]'

print(s.split("Name =")[1].split(",")[0].strip()[1:-1])
version
```

Or use [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import re

print(re.findall("Name\s+=\s+\"(.*?)\",",s)[0])
version
```

Comment: Maybe add a `?` to your regex in case there's a quote later on?

Comment: @DSM: good suggestion, as that may come up. I'm new to using regular expressions. Any idea where I should add the ? within the regex for that purpose?

Comment: @DSM, added but won't it still match `"version" "foo"`? I did not worry about it as I presumed there was always a comma after